# Query returns less rows when used in JDBC then SQL developer

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using JDBC to connect to oracle database using prepareStatement and executeQuery. But when I use the same query on database from SQL developer, I found that rows returned through JDBC are quite less than what they actually are.

Is this possible due to connection issues or query or statement. Can anyone help me out.

Here's the query I ran in SQL developer-

```
select count(*) 
from xxx 
where (TIME_STAMP between 
           TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-22 09:45:37.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff') 
           and TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-22 09:55:37.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff')) 
AND (customerid not like '[null]') 
AND (applicationid not like '[null]') 
and (status not like '-');
```

EDIT: I used a variable counter in while(resultSet.next()) to count number of rows returned, from where I got to know that number of rows returned are different. Here is the JDBC code below-

```
 String query = "select * from xxx where 
 (TIME_STAMP between TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-22 09:45:37.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff') and 
 TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-22 09:55:37.0','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff')) 
 AND (customerid not like '[null]') 
 AND (applicationid not like '[null]') 
 and (status not like '-')";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
 counter++; }
```

Comment: `select count(*) ` Your query will always return only 1 row i.e. just the count. Where is the question of multiple rows?

Comment: this is the query i used in SQL developer to check number of rows. In JDBC I used a variable in while(resultSet.next()) to check how many rows were returned

Comment: Please post the *exact* query that you have run both in SQL developer (complete statement) and via JDBC (complete `prepareStatement()` and `executeQuery()` calls). Because as it stands now, the answer is: You're not running the same query.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I have edited with complete details

Comment: @Jaydeep What happens when you use `count(*)` in your JDBC code too?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure that you connect to the same database. (If you have possible others that you use for testing or so)

Then, looking at your query, the most suspicious point seems to be the date conversions. You can analyze the two different result sets and check to see if the date period you entered matches with the results. If one of them contains unexpected results in terms of date values, then the issue may be related to default timezone of your Java Virtual Machine or Oracle Server.